# Why does this code produce an InvalidMemoryOperationError?

Tags: garbage-collection, d

The following code crashes with the error `core.exception.InvalidMemoryOperationError@(0)` when given a moderately large file (251MB) as input, but not when given small files.

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] argv) {
    foreach(line; stdin.byLine()) {}
}
```

All the documentation I've found [e.g. [1](http://dlang.org/library/core/exception/invalid_memory_operation_error.html), [2](http://wiki.dlang.org/InvalidMemoryOperationError)] suggests that this error occurs when allocation happens during a garbage collection cycle (e.g. if memory is allocated within a destructor).  But the only thing that should get allocated here is `line`, which is of type `char[]`, which presumably doesn't have a destructor.

Furthermore, since the values returned by byLine() aren't supposed to persist after popFront() is called on it [[3](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#byLine)], I'm curious as to why it's even allocating enough memory to *need* a collection pass.  Isn't the whole point of using byLine instead of byLineCopy the ability to reuse the buffer, growing it only as necessary?

My compiler version is `DMD64 D Compiler v2.067.1`

Comment: Is the file you are piping in a text e.g. UTF-8 file?
I have to ask, since, that seems odd. I looked at the code, it really just seems funky.

Comment: Plain ASCII text, and no lines longer than 5905 bytes.

Comment: cannot reproduce here (linux DMD64 2.069). Do you pass the input through another process (as suggested by Richard A.C)? If so It's quite possible that the process has to close the input (e.g launch process A, write to process A input, close process A input). In a console (eg `./test < input.txt`) there's no bug.

Comment: Can you post the file content?

Comment: Nested type, there was no other process; I was just redirecting a file to stdin.  Bauss, the file is 251MB, so not really.  Upgrading to 2.068.2 fixed it, so it looks like it was a bug in the 2.067.1 compiler.  (And possibly in earlier versions as well; the bug only manifested on large files.  It worked fine on a 2MB input on the old compiler, for instance, so Nested type's test doesn't show conclusively that it works on 2.069 in all cases.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely caused by this bug:
https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13856

Please try upgrading your DMD to the current release, it should be fixed there.

Comment: That did it.  I'm surprised it was an actual compiler bug; you don't see those often.